# How to integrate differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following equation
$$
\sum_{m=0}^M b_m r^m \left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac 2 r \frac{d}{dr}\right)\Psi =0.\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Multiplying the above equation by $r^n$ and then integrating gives:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^M b_m{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)\mu_{m+n-2}}=0 \label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where 
$$
\mu_j=\int_{0}^{\infty} r^j \Psi(r) dr,\label{3} \tag{3}
$$
assuming  that $\Psi$ and $\frac{d\Psi}{dr}$ vanish at infinity.

---

This is a part of a paper what I'm trying to reproduce its results. But I got into trouble when I tried to reach equation \eqref{2} from \eqref{1}. Any Idea?

Comment: How does one understand the first equation in view of the basic fact that if the product of two real factors is zero, then one of the factors has to be zero?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann I have eliminated the other terms to simplify the question.

Comment: It still does not make much sense. Do you mean that in the sense of truncated power series, that is, the right side is $O(r^N)$ for a suitably large $N$? There are no zero divisors in the space of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main crux is that $$\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac 2 r \frac{d}{dr}\right)\Psi = \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{d}{dr}\right)\Psi$$

So, integrating after multiplying by $r^n$ gives - 
$$\sum_{m=0}^M b_m \int_0^{\infty}r^{m+n-2}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{d}{dr}\right)\Psi dr= 0$$

Applying integration by parts, the $1^{st}$ term is $0$ (as $\Psi$ and $\frac{d\Psi}{dr} $vanish at $\infty$). So, we are left with -
$$\sum_{m=0}^M b_m \int_0^{\infty}r^2\frac{d\Psi}{dr}\frac{dr^{m+n-2}}{dr}dr= 0$$
or 
$$\sum_{m=0}^M b_m (m+n-2)\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d\Psi}{dr}r^{m+n-1}dr = 0$$
Again applying integration by parts, as the $1^{st}$ term is again $0$ for the same reasons, we get -
$$\sum_{m=0}^M b_m (m+n-2)\int_0^{\infty}\Psi\frac{dr^{m+n-1}}{dr}dr = 0$$
or 
$$\sum_{m=0}^M b_m (m+n-2)(m+n-1)\int_0^{\infty}\Psi r^{m+n-2}dr = 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot.However I didn't understand your way exactly, Is it possible to add more detail to your answer?

Comment: What I did essentially was, during integration by parts, was - $\int f\frac{dg}{dx} dx = fg|_0^{\infty} - \int g\frac{df}{dx} dx$, and $f,g$ are $0$ at $0$ and $\infty$

Comment: Ok. many thanks. And what about the first step of your answer?

Comment: That is essentially the radial part of the Laplacian operator. I recognized it, and knew that this identity holds.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.